# Debezium SQL Server Connector value of NCHAR

Tags: sql-server, decode, debezium, nvarchar, nchar

I am using debezium 1.5.0.Beta1 sqlserver connector with SQL Server 2019 and Kafka to capture CDC on my database. I have a problem with NCHAR and NVARCHAR values from database. In my table I have values: 
NCHAR -> N'あ' and
NVARCHAR -> N'こんにちは', and that is fine in database. But when I run debezium connector, it create event with string values of those two fields with values:
"Ńüé" and "ŃüôŃéôŃüźŃüíŃü»". 
Is there any why I can decode it back to あ and こんにちは?

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case as in Python's  `'こんにちは'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp775')` returns `'ŃüōŃéōŃü½ŃüĪŃü»'`. You _could_ reverse it as `'ŃüōŃéōŃü½ŃüĪŃü»'.encode( 'cp775').decode( 'utf-8')` (returns `'こんにちは'`) however fix it in your connector rather…

Comment: @JosefZ Thank you so much sir, that solved a problem.